# jquery validate plugin does not autocheck until after leaving field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Apologies for the code, I'm just starting out :)

I'm using jquery validation plugin, which is working fine, however it only updates automatically (i.e. shows inline error message while typing) after I've left a field by pressing tab then went back into it.

When I press tab to go to a new field, the validation kicks in and shows any errors, then I can go back to the field and it then starts updating automatically after every keypress.

Why is it not working without going out then back in?

Here's my jquery code:

```
<script>
jQuery.validator.addMethod("containNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/\d/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain a number");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("containUpper", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/[A-Z]/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain an uppercase character");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("containLower", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/[a-z]/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain a lowercase character");

$( "#passwordchange" ).validate({
  rules: {
    password1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 8,
      maxlength: 64,
      containNumber : true,
      containUpper: true,
      containLower: true
    },
    password2: {
        equalTo: '#password1'
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This behavior is by default and explained in the docs.  It's called "lazy validation".  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo

Comment: ah, ok, so that's how it works then, would be nice to be not so lazy. Is there a way to just force the validation on the field when the form is loaded?

Comment: If you want "eager" validation, then you'll need to provide over-riding `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` callback functions.